# PHP PDO group query results by column name

Tags: php, pdo

The following PDO query is returning the results below:

```
$db = new PDO('....');
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT ...');
```

These are the results:

```
 name   curso   
ABC stack
CDE stack
FGH stack
IJK stack
LMN overflow
OPQ overflow
RST overflow
```

I need to build the HTML like:

```
<p>stack</p>
ABC<br/>
CDE<br/>
...<br/>
<p>overflow</p>
LMN<br/>
OPQ<br/>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
$sth->execute();
  //$curso = $sth->fetch();
  $id = $sth->fetchColumn(1);
  echo "<p>".mb_convert_encoding($id,'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1').'</p>'; 
  while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo (mb_convert_encoding($row['name'],'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')).'<br/>';
  }
```

But this is removing the first name of each group, like:

```
 <p>stack</p>
    CDE<br/>
    ...<br/>
```

Comment: Well, you're doing fetchcolumn which will get the id and throws away the rest of the row, then get the next row with fetch...

Comment: I get the logic, but how to get the results grouped by 'curso'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this kind of code to print the result:

```
$sth->execute();
$curso = '';
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['curso'] !== $curso) {
        $curso = $row['curso'];
        echo '<p>' . mb_convert_encoding($curso, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1') . '</p>';
    }
    echo mb_convert_encoding($row['name'], 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1') . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some sort of built-in method, but this works, thanks!

Comment: My approach was to not change your initial code too much to make sure that it works. The other answer describes the built-in solution very well.

Answer (score 6):

That is an interesting question, because it does involve not only [*regular PDO feature* of grouping results](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group), but even more tricky parameter combination that can make the whole code even smoother:

- First, you have to use `fetchAll()` to get all the results from the query at once, instead of fetching them manually.
- Then you have to use PDO magic constant named `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` to group the results and have all the actual results nested in sub-arrays.
- And finally, you can combine it with another constant, `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`, to get already a column in a nested array!

Note that in order to use `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, you have to put a column to group by in the first position. So, change your code like this

```
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT curso, ...'); 
$sth->execute(...);
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

An now you have a grouped array you were looking for! Well, almost, as it will be a nested array which will have to processed like this

```
foreach ($data as $curso => $section) {
    echo "<p>$curso</p>"; 
    foreach ($section as $row) {
        echo $row['name']."<br>"; 
}
```

Yet, if you need only one column from in the group, we can use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`, to get it, making the code real smooth:

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach ($data as $curso => $names) {
    echo "<p>$curso</p>"; 
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, The 1st solution works perfectly. The 2nd is returning Notice: Use of undefined constant PDO_FETCH_COLUMN - assumed 'PDO_FETCH_COLUMN' in $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO_FETCH_COLUMN); And Notice: Array to string conversion echo $name."<br>";

Comment: It's a typo of mine. Shoukd be PDO::FETCH_COLUMN